# For the same C source code, why the sizes compiled on different machines are different

Tags: linux, command, size

For the following C code,

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

I compiled it with gcc command `gcc memory-layout.c -o memory-layout`

But the results I output using the size command on different Linux are different
[image: ParrotSec OS x86_64]

[image: CentOS x86_64]

Oops! There is a problem with the image upload, the size command output on ParrotSec OS x86_64 just like this:

```
size memory-layout
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1358     528       8    1894     766 memory-layout
```

on CentOS x86_64 :

```
size memory-layout
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1129     540       4    1673     689 memory-layout
```

I want to know why there is a difference in the value calculated by size, can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is `gcc --version` gives the same version ?  This may be because of different versions of `gcc`.

Comment: even though you were able to get the screen shots working, they are not prefered here on S.O. The copy/paste and clean formatting of the `size` output is much preferred. Good show! I don't do enough compiling anymore to be of help on that issue, but I would hazzard a guess that some of the `lib*.so` or `lib*.a` files that are linked in are different between the OSs. Good luck!

Comment: gcc version is different. Is this problem caused by different gcc versions?@anoopknr